# Join two sql grouped queries

Tags: sql, join

I have two grouped sql queries that I have joined.  The first query is pulling the part number, planner id, sum of quantity, and the cost. The second query, which is nested into the statement, is just the part number and a count of the number of transactions. I am joining the two queries on the part number. see code below.
I have done a good deal of searching on this and have gotten very close, but am still unable to get all the columns in the query. When I run the query I get the following:
prtnumb_15, planid_01, Qty, Cost. but I am missing the NoTrans (number of transactions) column. I don't know if my syntax is just off a bit or if I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT TH1.prtnum_15, PM1.planid_01, SUM(TH1.tnxqty_15) AS 'Qty', PM1.cost_01 * PM1.cstcnv_01 AS 'Cost'
FROM transaction_history TH1
 INNER JOIN part_master PM1
    ON TH1.prtnum_15 = PM1.prtnum_01  
 INNER JOIN
     (
      SELECT TH2.prtnum_15, COUNT (TH2.TNXQTY_15) AS NoTrans
      FROM transaction_history TH2
      WHERE 
      NOT (TH2.prtnum_15 LIKE '0%'
      OR TH2.prtnum_15 LIKE '1%'
      OR TH2.prtnum_15 LIKE '8%'
      OR TH2.prtnum_15 LIKE '9%'
      OR TH2.prtnum_15 LIKE 'X%'
      OR TH2.prtnum_15 LIKE 'Y%')
      AND TH2.tnxdte_15 BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-11 00:00:01'
      AND TH2.tnxcde_15 IN ('R')
      GROUP BY TH2.PRTNUM_15
      ) TH2 ON TH1.prtnum_15 = TH2.prtnum_15
WHERE 
      NOT (TH1.prtnum_15 LIKE '0%'
      OR TH1.prtnum_15 LIKE '1%'
      OR TH1.prtnum_15 LIKE '8%'
      OR TH1.prtnum_15 LIKE '9%'
      OR TH1.prtnum_15 LIKE 'X%'
      OR TH1.prtnum_15 LIKE 'Y%')
AND TH1.tnxcde_15 IN ('I')
AND TH1.tnxdte_15 BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-11 00:00:01'
GROUP BY TH1.PRTNUM_15, PM1.PLANID_01, PM1.cost_01 * PM1.cstcnv_01, TH2.NoTrans
ORDER BY TH1.prtnum_15
```

Comment: hmm there are no th2.NoTrans in the select fields, have u include it in the select?

Comment: It looks like you just need to add `TH2.NoTrans` to the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already commented you are just missing `NoTrans` in your outer select. you need to include that column. So change your outer select like

```
SELECT TH1.prtnum_15, 
PM1.planid_01, 
SUM(TH1.tnxqty_15) AS 'Qty', 
PM1.cost_01 * PM1.cstcnv_01 AS 'Cost',
TH2.NoTrans
FROM transaction_history TH1
......

<rest of your query>

......
```